# How to whitelist egress traffic with a NetworkPolicy that doesn't prevent Apache Ignite from starting up?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, port, policy-routing, network-namespace

I have some more or less complex microservice architecture, where Apache Ignite is used as a stateless database / cache. The Ignite `Pod` is the only `Pod` in its `Namespace` and the architecture has to pass a security audit, which it won't pass if I don't apply the most restrictive `NetworkPolicy` possible for `egress` traffic. It has to restrict all possible traffic that is not needed by Ignite itself.

At first, I thought: *Nice, Ignite does not push any traffic to other `Pod`s (there are no other pods in that `Namespace`), so this is gonna be easily done restricting all `egress` traffic in the `Namespace` where Ignite is the only `Pod`!* ...

Well, that didn't actually work out great:
Any `egress` rule, even if I allow traffic to all the ports mentioned in the Ignite Documentation, will cause the startup to fail with an `IgniteSpiException` that says **Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses**, `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)`.

The problem seems to be the [`TcpDiscoveryKubernetsIpFinder`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/kubernetes/TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.html), especially the method `getRegisteredAddresses(...)` which obviously does some egress traffic inside the `Namespace` in order to register IP addresses of Ignite nodes. The disovery port 47500 is of course allowed, but that does not change the situation. The functionality of Ignite with the other `Pod`s from other `Namespace`s is working without `egress` rules applied, which means (to me) that the configuration concerning `ClusterRole`, `ClusterRoleBinding`, a `Service` in the `Namespace` and the xml configuration of Ignite itself etc. seems to be correct. Even `ingress` rules restricting traffic from other namespaces are working as expected, allowing exactly the desired traffic.

These are the policies I applied:

**[WORKING, blocking undesired traffic only]**:

```yaml
## Denies all Ingress traffic to all Pods in the Namespace
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all-ingress-in-cache-ns
  namespace: cache-ns
spec:
  # selecting nothing here will deny all traffic between pods in the namespace
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  # traffic routes to be considered, here: incoming exclusively
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
```

```yaml
## Allows necessary ingress traffic
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: netpol-cache-ns
  namespace: cache-ns
# defines the pod(s) that this policy is targeting
spec:
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  # <----incoming traffic----
  ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: somewhere-else
        podSelector:
          matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values: [some-pod, another-pod]  # dummy names, these Pods don't matter at all
      ports:
        - port: 11211   # JDBC
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47100   # SPI communication
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47500   # SPI discovery (CRITICAL, most likely...)
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 10800   # SQL
          protocol: TCP
# ----outgoing traffic---->
# NONE AT ALL
```

With these two applied, everything is working fine, but the security audit will say something like
*Where are the restrictions for `egress`? What if this node is hacked via the allowed routes because one of the Pods using these routes was hacked before? It may call a C&C server then! This configuration will not be permitted, harden your architecture!*

**[BLOCKING desired/necessary traffic]**:

Generally deny all traffic...

```yaml
## Denies all traffic to all Pods in the Namespace
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all-traffic-in-cache-ns
  namespace: cache-ns
spec:
  # selecting nothing here will deny all traffic between pods in the namespace
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  # traffic routes to be considered, here: incoming exclusively
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress   # <------ THIS IS THE DIFFERENCE TO THE WORKING ONE ABOVE
```

... and allow specific routes afterwards

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: netpol-cache-ns-egress
  namespace: cache-ns
# defines the pod(s) that this policy is targeting
spec:
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  ----outgoing traffic---->
  egress:
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow egress to this namespace at specific ports
    - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: cache-zone
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 10800
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 47100   # SPI communication
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 47500
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow dns resolution in general (no namespace or pod restriction)
    - ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 53
      - protocol: UDP
        port: 53
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow egress to the kube-system (label is present!)
    - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: kube-system
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow egress in this namespace and for the ignite pod
    - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: cache-zone
        podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: ignite
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow traffic to the IP address of the ignite pod
    - to:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 172.21.70.49/32  # won't work well since those addresses are dynamic
      ports:
        - port: 11211   # JDBC
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47100   # SPI communication
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47500   # SPI discovery (CRITICAL, most likely...)
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 49112   # JMX
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 10800   # SQL
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8080    # REST
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 10900   # thin clients
          protocol: TCP
```

Apache Ignite version used is 2.10.0

Now the question to all readers is:

How can I restrict `Egress` to an absolute minimum inside the `Namespace` so that Ignite starts up and works correctly? Would it be sufficient to just deny `Egress` to outside the cluster?

If you need any more `yaml`s for an educated guess or hint, please feel free to request them in a comment.
And sorry for the tagging if it seems inappropriate, I couldn't find the tag `kubernetes-networkpolicy` as it is present on stackoverflow.

### **UPDATE:**

Executing `nslookup -debug kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` from inside the ignite pod wihtout any policy restricting `egress` shows

```
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nslookup HOST [DNS_SERVER]

Query DNS about HOST
```

As soon as (any) `NetworkPolicy` is applied that restricts `Egress` to specific ports, pods and namespaces the Ignite pod refuses to start and the lookup does not reach `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` anymore.

`Egress` to DNS was allowed (UDP 53 to k8s-app: kube-dns) ⇒ still no ip lookup possible

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: Cloud provider and I am currently updating the cluster and the workers to 1.21